# How do I view the beer for the next rotation?

Tags: fiz

I'm having a hard time keeping Der Vaterland stocked since its rotation is so short.  I've been doing a lot of research but I can't seem to figure out what is coming during the next rotation.  Is there a way I can view that (assuming I've done the research already?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only way it seems is to just write it down as reference.  Der Vaterland seems to be on a fixed rotation of these brews:

March - May (Lenten):  Dopplebock
May - July (Spring):  Maibock
July - September Week 2 (Summer):  Helles
September Week 2 - November (Oktoberfest):  Octoberfest
November - March (Winter):  Dunkel, German Pilsner, Hefeweizen

Answer (score 6):

There are 5 Seasons at this Store.  It follows loosely the German tradition of drinking certain types of beer during certain times of the year.  This was developed over hundreds of years time, well before there was refrigeration or cultivation of yeast strains. So the German weather forced brewers to make certain beers during those months.

Example: a **Maibock** (Mai = May), which is drank during the month of May typically is actually brewed 3 months prior in order to fully ferment and be ready to drink that month.

- Lenten Season (M3-M4) - **Dopplebock**
- Spring Season (M5-M6) - **Maibock**
- Summer Season (M7-M8) - **Hellen**
- Oktoberfest (M9-M11) - **Oktoberfest**
- Winter Season (M12-M2) - **Hefenwiezen**, **Dunkel**, **German Pilsner**

I suggest building up the amount of storage to have 4-5 slots open and then keeping one of each type available for the appropriate season. Do this until you complete the challenge.